# Having problem with HttpClient - PostAsJsonAsync in blazor

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to use the `PostAsJsonAsync` in the same way it used to work `PostJsonAsync` before been updated, but Im getting this error:

CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'ICCR.Shared.LoginModel' to 'ICCR.Shared.LoginResult'   ICCR.Client

And the registerModel in the code bellow its marked in red, I would thank if you tell me how to solve it.

```
public async Task<RegisterResult> Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
    
        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<RegisterResult>("api/accounts", registerModel);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why do have a `PostAsJsonAsync<RegisterResult>` with a `RegisterModel ` value ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PostAsJsonAsync() returns an HttpResponseMessage.

```
public async Task<RegisterResult> Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
{    
   var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accounts", registerModel);
   return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<RegisterResult>();
}
```

the type of the input parameter for Post() can be inferred, the return type from Read() has to be specified with `<>`.

Comment: I noticed that before by investigating more, thats the real solution

Comment: Henk for the president!